# How to convert typescript async/await code as it is to javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I am exploring hap17 async/await. My code is working fine but I am curious why it is converting ts code in different format. Means If I do not set `"module": "commonjs"` in tsconfig file then, after tsc it generate js code which convert await to _awaiter with switch case. If I set `"module": "commonjs"` then it convert await to yield. Why it is so?
And what if I want to convert same await in js file. Then what should be the configuration?

My tsconfig file is like

```
`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
    },
    "include": [
        "web/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}`
```

Ts file code

```
var server = new Hapi.Server({
  listener: http2.createServer(),
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000,
  tls: true,
})

const init = async () => {
    try {
      await server.register({register: routes, name: "test"})
      await server.start();
      console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
};

init();
```

when I do `tsc` I am expecting same code in js file also ie async/await.
But it convert async await to following format

```
const init = () => tslib_1.__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    try {
        yield server.register({ register: base_route_1.default, name: "test" });
        yield server.start();
        console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
init();
```

Comment: `"target": "es6",` in your compiler options. ES6 does not know what `async/await` is, so it gets converted. If you want to keep the code "as is", then you want `"target": "es7",`. If you actually want it to run in lower spec environments, then just leave it as it is.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now as expected.